# Form: Why `key.currentState` is null prior the user modifies the text field?

Tags: flutter, forms, dart, validation

I am implementing a multi-screen form allowing the user to fill in the properties of a classified ad.

Each step handles a bunch of properties. For simplicity, I've selected a single property form below that collects the ad description.

Here is the code:

```dart
// == The field initialised with the current ad description
// I expect it to be validatable already

FormBuilderTextField(
  initialValue: _ad.description,
  autofocus: true,
  maxLines: 4,
  decoration: _inputDecoration(
    labelText: "Description de l’annonce"),
    name: 'description',
    validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
      FormBuilderValidators.required(),
      FormBuilderValidators.minLength(6),
    ]),
    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
    onChanged: (v) =>
      setState(() => _ad.description = v ?? ""),
    )),
  ])),

  // == Continue button at the bottom

  _continueButton(
    ifValidField: "description",
    pushWidget: ClassifiedAdCreationPriceScreen(ad: _ad),
  ),
```

Where the simplified version of `_continueButton` is as follows:

```dart
  /// Returns the large continue button that enables the user to get to the next step
  /// If the field [ifValidField] is valid, then we can go to the next step, otherwise we stay there
  /// The continue button is only enabled if we cancontinue.
  /// When we are ready to get to the next screen, the ad is stored to the database
  Widget _continueButton({
    /// The field name to evaluate if provided.
    String? ifValidField,

   
    /// The widget to push for the next step if provided
    Widget? pushWidget,
  }) {

    late final bool canContinue;


    if (_formKey.currentState?.fields[ifValidField]?.isValid ?? false) {
      canContinue = true;
    } else {
      canContinue = false;
    }

    void Function()? onPressed;

    if (canContinue) {
      onPressed = () {
        try {
          _ad.storeUpdate();
        } catch (e) {
          setState(() => _error = e.toString());
          return;
        }


        if (_formKey.currentState!.saveAndValidate()) {
          push(pushWidget);
        }
      };
    }

    return _rawContinueButton(onPressed: onPressed);
  }

  /// The raw continue button which spans thru the width up the screen
  /// Shouldn't be used directly: use [_continueButton] instead.
  Widget _rawContinueButton(
      {
      /// the text of the button
      String? text,

      /// the onPressed callback
      required void Function()? onPressed}) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: onPressed,
              child: Text(text ?? i18n_Continue.i18n),
            )));
  }
```

The system allows the user to return several times to the form, while the ad is not yet published to complete it.

Then, at this stage, the screen displays the multi-line text field, initialized with the description of the current ad draft.

To go to the next step, a `Continue` button sits at the bottom of the screen: it remains disabled as long as the form cannot validate.

My problem is that `_formkey.currentState` remains null as long as the user does not make any changes to the content of the field.

How it comes `_formkey.currentState` is null?

How should I update my code to let the user continue when the initial value validates?